# Trying to supply a ToolBar instead of an ActionBar

Tags: android

I wanted to Substitute a ToolBar instead of an ActionBar. Here is my `styles.xml` content

```
<resources>
...
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
...
</resources>
```

Here Goes my Manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <service android:name=".CustomFloating" android:label="Floating Class"/>
</application>
```

And, Here is the layout, where I wish to implement this style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="sports.scores.floating.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyTheme"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am facing the same error in all the layout files, though I have set the value of `windowActionBar` to false. Here is my MainActivity class content.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//line number 34
    ...
}
```

But Still, I am getting this stacktrace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
        at sports.scores.floating.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
```

Can someone please help me out with this. I wish to substitute this actionbar with *my_awesome_toolbar*.

Comment: you should use a No Action Bar Theme if you provide custom toolbar

Comment: <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: bt I have set windowActionbar property to false. What sense does it make, if I use NoActionBar

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: How do I change the color of the toolBar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Modify style**

```
 <resources>
...
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
...
</resources>
```

Comment: That's Not Working. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I take my words back. That worked. But Now, How do I change Color of my ToolBar ??

Comment: add in your xml : android:background="@android:color/transparent"